# Sending post requests to other controllers from root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm completely new to rails so apologies for the simple question...

I have a one page rails app and I'm having issues creating new instances of my models from the root path to save to the database.

I have tried using form_for but when I press submit it tries to post to '/' rather than to '/MODEL'.

I get the error: No route matches [POST] "/"

I realise this might be a simple routing issue but I haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for on the web.

Additionally, if anyone could point me to some in depth resources that goes into things like this I would greatly appreciate it.
I've gone through "Rails Tutorial" but I feel like it only give a birds eye view on how Rails work rather than why.

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static#home'
  devise_for :users
  resources :card_log
end
```

and the segment of the view file:

```
      = form_for :card_log do |f|
    %p
      = f.label :item1
      = f.text_field :item1
    %p
      = f.label :item2
      = f.text_field :item2
    %p
      = f.label :item3
      = f.text_field :item3
    %p
      = f.submit "Submit"
```

Comment: how about posting your `routes.rb` and/or the result of `rake routes`

Comment: If you want to learn the "why" of Rails, I have found the book "Rebuilding Rails" by Noah Gibbs to be very excellent. If you want help debugging your code, please post the routes.rb file and the view file that contains the form.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Thomas, also, have edited my response with routes and view snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The best in-depth resource for `form_for` comes from the [Ruby on Rails edge guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).

If your case, make sure you have the following in routes.rb. Replace `:models` with each of your actual model names:

```
resources :models
```

In your views, the following should work for creating a new instance of Model.

```
form_for(@model)
```

You can also define your routes explicitly like so:

```
form_for(@model, url: model_path(@model), html: {method: "post"})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I had a go doing this and now I get this error: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"card_log", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]` and it highlights this code  `= form_for @cards, url: card_log_path(@cards), html: {method: "post"} do |f|` I don't understand why it is trying to do a Show action.